# USPS Tracking API Expected Delivery Date?

Tags: xml, web-services, api, usps

I am integrating USPS tracking API into my current project and need some help getting all the tracking info. Basically, my requests are done by the following URL:

http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=

This request(once I input my correct ID) returns a XML page containing a summary, tracking id, and package's locations , but it doesn't have any tags regarding the expected delivery date(the tracking id used has one). My question is how do I get the expected delivery info to show up on the XML ? I am certain there should be a way to get that info as other companies like Amazon and Ebay have a "expected delivery date" along with all the tracking info. I tried reading the USPS manual(https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm.pdf) on the API but it doesn't really explain well. If anyone can make sense of it and help me out, I would be highly greatful. Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expected delivery date is available through "TrackFieldRequest"

### Example Request

```
<TrackFieldRequest USERID="xxxxxxxx">
<Revision>1</Revision>
<ClientIp>127.0.0.1</ClientIp>
<SourceId>John Doe</SourceId>
    <TrackID ID="010850921250125054">
        <DestinationZipCode>12345</DestinationZipCode>
        <MailingDate>2010-01-01</MailingDate>
   </TrackID>
</TrackFieldRequest>
```

### Example Request Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TrackResponse>
     <TrackInfo ID="9102969010383081813033">
         <ExpectedDeliveryDate>March 9, 2012</ExpectedDeliveryDate>
          ...
     </TrackInfo>
</TrackResponse>
```

Source:
https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm.htm#_Toc378923168

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, I just ran across this recently. Maybe someone out there is looking for a similar solution.

I'm having a similar issue with estimated delivery date not being in the results. This worked for me:

```
https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrackFieldRequest USERID="XXXX">
<Revision>1</Revision>
<ClientIp>122.3.3</ClientIp>
<SourceId>XYZ Corp</SourceId>
<TrackID ID="XXXX"></TrackID>
</TrackFieldRequest>
```

This will provide a field called "PredictedDeliveryDate" and "OnTime" which seem very similar to their expecteddeliverydate

Reference url: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm-api.htm